# iText 7 borderless table (no border)

Tags: java, itext, itext7

This code below does not work.

```java
Table table = new Table(2); 
table.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
```

I am new to iText 7 and all I wanted is to have my table borderless.
Like how to do it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The table itself is by default not responsible for borders in iText7, the cells are. You need to set every cell to be borderless if you want a borderless table (or set the outer cells to have no border on the edge if you still want inside borders).

```
Cell cell = new Cell();
cell.add("contents go here");
cell.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
table.addCell(cell);
```

Comment: I tried this one sir but an error occurred in "cell.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER)" saying CANNOT FIND SYMBOL "NO_BORDER"

Comment: ah sorry my problem. import problem. tnxxx

Comment: As per [iText 7.1.6](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/7.1.6/com/itextpdf/layout/element/Cell.html) you can't add a `String` to `Cell` anymore, only `IBlockElement` or `Image`.

Comment: iText 7.1.10 with C# you can do it that way:  .table.AddCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph("contents").SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER)));

Answer (score 13):

You could write a method which runs though all children of a Table and sets NO_BORDER.

```
private static void RemoveBorder(Table table)
{
    for (IElement iElement : table.getChildren()) {
        ((Cell)iElement).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
    }
}
```

This gives you the advantage that you can still use

```
table.add("whatever");
table.add("whatever");
RemoveBorder(table);
```

instead of changing it on all cells manual.

Comment: Very convenient. I'd suggest a bit more type safety with: `table.GetChildren().OfType<Cell>()`

Answer (score 0):

An utility function I define in my java code bases is the following:

```
private static void setInnerCellBorder(Table table, Border border) {
    for (IElement child : table.getChildren()) {
        if (child instanceof Cell) {
            ((Cell) child).setBorder(border);
        }
    }
}
```

Then if you want no borders you can call the function as follows:

```
setInnerCellBorder(table, Border.NO_BORDER);
// or if you want a different color size you can do 
setInnerCellBorder(Table, new SolidBorder(ColorConstants.RED, 2));
```