# Removing Border from Table in iText7

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

I want to remove the entire border of a table in iText 7.

Until [7.0.8](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/7.0.8/com/itextpdf/layout/element/Cell.html) it was possible to add strings to cells ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41608146/1170330)):

```
Cell cell = new Cell();
cell.add("contents go here");
cell.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
table.addCell(cell);
```

But as per [7.1.6](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/7.1.6/com/itextpdf/layout/element/Cell.html) strings can't be added to cells anymore, only `IBlockElement` or `Image`.

This one would be a workaround:

```
Cell cell;

cell = new Cell().add(new Paragraph("some text"));
cell.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
table.addCell(cell);

cell = new Cell().add(new Paragraph("more text"));
cell.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
table.addCell(cell);

// repeat x times
```

But it obviously isn't the preferred way if you have many cells.

---

So how can I remove the border of a table now?

Simply doing `table.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER)` has no effect.

Answer (score 4):

By default, cells have borders in iText7 (0.5px solid black). So if you want to add a cell without border you should specify it by setting NO_BORDER as a cell border.

On the other hand, tables don't have borders by default, that's why `table.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER)` has no effect on the resultant pdf.

So I'm afraid, but you should use the `cell.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);` approach.

As for adding a string to a cell: yes, one should add a paragraph now. The string-parameterized method was removed, because it wasn't quite clear how this string should be wrapped inside a cell

Comment: So I should specify it for every single cell? Isn't there a faster, more efficient way?

Comment: One of the options I see is extending the Cell class and overriding the getDefaultProperty method. You should make it return null for Property.BORDER